# Qml Locale has same format for ShortFormat and NarrowFormat

Tags: qt, qml, qdate, qlocale

I'm trying to display the date (and time) using the toLocaleDateString / toLocateTimeString methods implemented on the Date type in Qml ([doc here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html)). It works, except for the ShortFormat which is the same as the NarrowFormat.

Here's an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property var locale: Qt.locale()

    Label {
        id: date
        text: {
            "DATE: \n" +
              "Locale.LongFormat:\t" + new Date().toLocaleDateString(locale, Locale.LongFormat) + "\n" +
              "Locale.ShortFormat:\t" + new Date().toLocaleDateString(locale, Locale.ShortFormat) + "\n" +
              "Locale.NarrowFormat:\t" + new Date().toLocaleDateString(locale, Locale.NarrowFormat) + "\n"
        }
        anchors.top : parent
    }

    Label {
        id: time
        text:
            "TIME: \n" +
              "Locale.LongFormat:\t" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString(locale, Locale.LongFormat) + "\n" +
              "Locale.ShortFormat:\t" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString(locale, Locale.ShortFormat) + "\n" +
              "Locale.NarrowFormat:\t" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString(locale, Locale.NarrowFormat) + "\n"

        anchors.top: date.bottom
    }

}
```

What's displayed:

```
Locale.LongFormat:  Wednesday, September 27, 2017
Locale.ShortFormat: 9/27/17
Locale.NarrowFormat:    9/27/17

Locale.LongFormat:  11:46:10 AM CEST
Locale.ShortFormat: 11:46 AM
Locale.NarrowFormat:    11:46 AM
```

I was expecting the ShotFormat to give me the date as Sept 27th 2017 or something similar, and the time as 11:46:42 AM.

I found in the doc ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-locale.html)), about the NarrowFormat, that

> Also, for the system locale this format is the same as ShortFormat.

I'm not sure if this is related to my issue, since I'm explicitly giving the locale in the toLocaleDateMethod. Even then, the NarrowFormat should then be more verbose, instead of the ShortFormat being shorter...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It also says "Note that the narrow format might contain the same text for different months and days or it can even be an empty string if the locale doesn't support narrow names, so you should avoid using it for date formatting." Makes you wonder why it's there in the first place if you can't use it.

Comment: I've got the same result here, Windows 7, Qt 5.9.1. Short and Narrow formats are the same, and do not match the description in the docs, for any locale I have tried. It seems that only one thing is guaranteed, that they are shorter then the LongFormat!

Answer (score 0):

In Qml Documentation:

`Locale.ShortFormat` is the default and recommended format, as `Locale.NarrowFormat` may not be fully supported by each locale (see Locale String Format Types) and `Locale.LongFormat` may not fit within the header cells.